# Filling a matrix from a dataframe

Tags: r, matrix

I have a dataframe which consists of 3 variables of interest

**loc1** - a location in a woodland

**loc2** - all the same locations as in loc 1

**ninds** - which is the weekly average number of individuals seen at loc1 which are subsequently then seen at any of the other locations in the woodland over the course of a year
(you can ignore the last two cols, not important for this question)

```
> head(shared2015)
  loc1 loc2      ninds         p.d       p.sym
1   1A   1A 36.0000000 1.000000000 1.000000000
2   1B   1A  2.3333333 0.028243818 0.019634878
3   1C   1A  0.2222222 0.002828977 0.001951522
4   1D   1A  0.1250000 0.002155172 0.001373626
5   1E   1A  0.2222222 0.009460548 0.004568106
6   1F   1A  0.0000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
```

I am trying to fill a matrix with rows named loc1 and cols named loc2 which then displays shared individuals between those sites

so I've created a blank matrix filled with NAs

```
site.loc2<-sapply(shared2015,function(a)unique(shared2015$loc2))
site.loc1<-sapply(shared2015,function(a)unique(shared2015$loc1))
site.loc1<-site.loc1[,1]
site.loc2<-site.loc2[,1]
n.sites<-length(site.loc2)
share.x<-matrix(NA,n.sites, n.sites, dimnames = list(site.loc1,site.loc2))
```

The next step is where I am completely lost, I can't find a way to fill the matrix in the way I want to
Ideally what I would like it something like this where I can see all the locations and all the individuals shared between them

```
    1A  1B  1C ...
1A  36  2.3 0.2
1B  2.3 86  6.7
```

first time posting here so go easy....
and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
share.x[as.matrix(shared2015[, c("loc1", "loc2")])] <- shared2015$ninds
```

Comment: @Keith. If this answer has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could `select` the relevant columns and then get the data in wide format. If you want `loc1` as rownames you can use `column_to_rownames`.

```
library(dplyr)

shared2015 %>%
  select(loc1:ninds) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = loc2, values_from = ninds) %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames('loc1')
```